# How to add a header image to RSS using SyndicationFeed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rss

I have successfully generated an RSS using SyndicationItem and SyndicationFeed

```
var item = new SyndicationItem
            (
                title: Title,
                content: Subtitle,
                itemAlternateLink: new Uri("http://mysite/" + Id)
            );
            item.PublishDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Dt).ToUniversalTime();
            item.Summary = new TextSyndicationContent(Subtitle);
            items.Add(item);
```

I generate the feed with:

```
SyndicationFeed feed = new SyndicationFeed("RSS feed", "http://mysite/Rss", Request.Url, items);
```

I would like to add an image to the RSS header, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [ImageUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.imageurl.aspx) property on the SyndicationFeed instance:

```
feed.ImageUrl = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
```